# What are the major differences (pros/cons) between ember-model, ember-restless, and emu?

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js, ember-data

A [recent ember-data blog update](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html) has suggested to look at [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model), [ember-restless](https://github.com/endlessinc/ember-restless), and [emu](https://github.com/charlieridley/emu) as alternatives to ember-data to communicate with conventional APIs.  Can you please provide a in-depth comparison of these libraries?

Comment: I'm looking for the following features in a library: camelcase/underscore JSON conversion, per-field errors, current and future support/maintenance, and some simple relationship support.  This is in addition to the features listed for each library.

Comment: You might want to add ember-orbit to that list now as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Of the three, I have only used ember-model (and of course ember-data).
However, I did evaluate the other two, ember-restless, and emu as well.

I picked ember-model because of the following reasons:

- Created and maintained by Erik Bryn, who is also a core EmberJs team member

  - This is important to me because I have a view to switch to ember-data when it is ready, and ember-model appears to be most aligned, both in syntax and style, to ember-data
- BYO$A (bring your own AJAX) - ember-model is not prescriptive at all about where resources should be.

  - No need to worry about URL path conventions, and needing to override them
  - Allows me to construct my own XMLHttpRequest, and do whatever processing necessary before loading the records
  - (ember-restless and emu behave mostly like ember-model' RESTAdapter, and do not give this degree of flexibility)

Although I have not personally used emu, I would say that its unqiue feature is that it has built in [support for push updates to models](https://github.com/charlieridley/emu#receiving-updates-from-server). While this is a rather nifty feature to have, it was not a requirement for me, and I chose ember-model.

While this is not quite the in-depth comparison that you asked for, it was enough for me to make a choice, HTH.